# Video Grabber from webpages

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, download-manager

IDM can "grab videos" a "Download This Video" button pops up whenever you are watching a video anywhere in the Internet, and its shows the video size, and when clicked, allows you to download it.

Is there any other software that can do this ?

I want to know the size of videos before I watch them (so I know their approx quality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of firefox addons that do that including:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/netvideohunter-video-downloade/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/

As always, beware relevant copyright issues.